# How to create a layout to Landscape and Portrait orientation

Tags: android, xml

Please help me set Android layout using XML.

I want to set layout orientation for portrait and landscape, but they are not responsive. When I see in portrait, it looks fine, but when I see in landscape, it does not.

This is my code:

```
<Linear Layout XML:android="HTTP://sachems.android.com/apk/res/android"
    XML:tools="HTTP://sachems.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@draw able/home"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Linear Layout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weight Sum="100" >
        <Linear Layout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin Top="370dp"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_book"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_margin Left="5dp"
                android:layout_margin Right="5dp"
                android:layout_margin Top="100dp"
                android:layout_margin Bottom="10dp"
                android:background="#66FF0000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Book"
                android:text Size="20sp" />
        </Linear Layout>


    </Linear Layout>
</Linear Layout>
```

This looks good only for one side orientation, either portrait or landscape, in Android tablet after running the application, but not in both when check by rotating the tablet.

Comment: You want to run in portrait mode only or both?

Comment: `Linear Layout` is **wrong** and won't compile. Use `LinearLayout`, instead. Also, please **avoid nesting** layouts. For better performances.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly you want to have one layout for portrait mode and second layout for horizontal. To do that you will need two separate XML files with the same name placed in `layout-land` and `layout-port` folder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make another layout for landscape then put it in

res -> layout-land folder .

Both the names of the xml are must be same for which is used for portrait and landscape .

Comment: can I still use `layout-land` folder now?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="HTTP://sachems.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="95"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_book"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="#66FF0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Book"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this way the book button will always be there at the bottom. Is that what u are looking for?

Comment: let me know if it helps

Answer (score -1):

Create same name layout in `rec=>layout`

Create new directory `layout-land`

[image]

And add xml file in `layout-land` directory

** main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout XML:android="HTTP://sachems.android.com/apk/res/android"
XML:tools="HTTP://sachems.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@draw able/home"
android:orientation=horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weight Sum="100" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin Top="370dp"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_book"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin Left="5dp"
            android:layout_margin Right="5dp"
            android:layout_margin Top="100dp"
            android:layout_margin Bottom="10dp"
            android:background="#66FF0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Book"
            android:text Size="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And out of `Layout-land` directory is same name xml but `orientation` is change xml

**main.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout XML:android="HTTP://sachems.android.com/apk/res/android"
XML:tools="HTTP://sachems.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@draw able/home"
android:orientation="virtical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="virtical"
    android:weight Sum="100" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin Top="370dp"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:orientation="virtical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_book"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin Left="5dp"
            android:layout_margin Right="5dp"
            android:layout_margin Top="100dp"
            android:layout_margin Bottom="10dp"
            android:background="#66FF0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Book"
            android:text Size="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```